# How to implement cell select in VBA excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to copy data from ws1 (worksheet1) to ws2 (worksheet2).
I want to select cell G2 in ws2.

If I use `.Range("G2").Select` do not work.
If I use `ws2.Range("G2").Select` result is debug error (Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed). I was trying few places and combinations. No idea how to select G2 and come back ws1 at the end of macro...

Macro:

```
Sub COPY_SA()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
'change Sheets to suit
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")

With ws1
    'assumung that data stored in column C:E, Sheet1
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'can not make range from row 3 ???
    Set rng = .Range("C1:F" & lastrow)
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        'apply filter with criteria in column 3 of range C:E
        'can not make filter in row 2 ???
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
        On Error Resume Next
        'get only visible rows
        Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'copy range
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Range("A:D").Copy
    'paste from row 3
    ws2.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    'delete no needed row
    ws2.Rows(3).Delete
    ws2.UsedRange.Columns("C:E").Calculate
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
  If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ws1.Range("2:2").AutoFilter
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide a hard copy of what both sheet look like. The code expect some filter to be set in ws1 sheet. **General Advice:** Instead of using Select and computing hard coded cell address it is better to use **Offset** and **Resize** ona Range object. You an also use named cells instead to reference hard coded cell address.

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove the with block's and reference ws1,ws2 and rng explicitly.

Comment: `Select` only works if the worksheet is active. You need to `ws2.activate` then `ws2.range().select`. **But** I don't advise selecting cells.

Comment: I wanted to select cell because macro end up with selection of few columns (what was copied). Any other simple way to remove selection?

Comment: In that case I see why you want/need it. As I said activate the sheet first and it should work

Comment: Your answer is simple and works :) Thanks a lot